# C#: Can't debug ASHX handler

Tags: c#, debugging, handler, ashx

I have an ASP.net C# 4.0 website project. I am calling an ASHX handler using a jQuery AJAX postback.  Normally when I debug C#, I use this method Debug > Attach to Process > select w3wp.exe and start debugging.

When I do this with my ASHX handler Visual Studio says "The breakpoint will not be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."  Sure enough, when I run the AJAX call to the handler, the breakpoint is not hit.

What confuses me is that I can debug C# files otherwise, i.e. the code-behind of an ASPX file.

Comment: If you have the project, and therefore the source, why do you need to manually bind the debugger at all?

Comment: Because the site is part of a content management solution, which entails that I need to be logged in.  I prefer to use my existing web browser session otherwise I have to jump through many more steps to get the part I want to debug.  You mark me down for that?  Nice.

Comment: Sorry Grant - i was being presumptuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Visual Studio will not actually load symbols for debugging until it actually tries to run the ASHX handler. My problem turned out to be elsewhere - a bug in the jQuery code that called the handler.

I didn't see this bug at first so assumed the handler was being hit.  Once the handler is called, VS will then allow you to debug it.  I didn't realise that ASHX handlers behaved this way, I thought they would work just like a regular C# file.

Comment: They all work this way. You'll notice that changing something in an aspx page and saving and setting a breakpoint will cause the 'error' breakpoint symbol, when you refresh the page _then_ you can see all of the symbols being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally because what you are looking at (the code) is not what you are running.

Try to throw in `Debugger.Launch();` and see if that attaches the debugger correctly. If it does then your problem is simply that you are view a different copy/version of the code that's unrelated to the debugging

Answer (score 0):

Is there only one w3wp.exe try right clicking your asp.net project select "Debug" and "Start a new instance" from context menu.

Comment: Yes only one instance of w3wp.exe